# Can't install printer

Tags: printing, canon

After upgradeing my system to Ubuntu 15.04 I can't my printer (Canon 4350d).
I add my printer via localhost:631 (cups) but it's not added at System -> Printers.
Cups displays all printers on the network, but I can't print and can't add printer in System -> Printers.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the "Share This Printer" option within the CUPS settings of the printer.
This made my printers available after upgrading to 15.04.
I hope this solves the problem for you.

Comment: Thank you, Bernd Schuhmacher. Sorry for my english. I tried setting the "Share This Printer" option within the CUPS settings of the printer. The printer tried to print, but stoped. I found the problem. When I tried to add a printer (I needed a shared printer on another computer), the system wanted print in Local RAW, but I tried to connect to the server cups as a remote printer. When I left the default settings, the printer began to print. 
Thanks again for your reply. Good luck!